# Update content with db-changes?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm using two Tabs to show unpaid and paid bills. So far I can pay an unpaid bills, and it will disappear from "`Unpaid`" tab. However, I'm having problem to add the newly paid bill to the Paid tabs with AJAX. I've to refresh the page in order to show it in the paid-Tabs.

I separate paid and unpaid bills by a `bool Paid` property in database.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1" type="">Un-paid</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Paid</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            if (item.Paid == false)
            {
                <div class="item">
                    <button class="btnPay" style="color: green"  data-id="@item.Id">Pay</button>                  
                    <br/>
                    <b>Payed by: </b> @item.User.FirstName  
                    <br/>        
                    <b>Total payment: </b> @item.TotSum
                    ....                                                  
                </div>
           }    
        }
    </div>    
    <div id="tabs-2">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {                  
            if (item.Paid == true)
            {      
              <div class="item">
                 <button class="btnRefund" style="color: red" data-id="@item.Id">Refund</button>
                  <br/>
                  <b>Payed by: </b> @item.User.FirstName  
                  <br/>        
                  <b>Total payment: </b> @item.TotSum
                  ....
              </div>
            }                     
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

My AJAX code for Unpaid-tab:

```
$('.btnPay').click(function() {
    var payId = $(this).data('id');
    var container = $(this).closest('.item');
    if (payId != '') {
        // changes "paid = false" to true in database
        $.post("/Home/PayBill", { "id": payId }, function(data) {
            if (data) { //if true, hides the newly paid bill from unpaid-tab
                $(container).slideUp(300, function() {
                    $(this).fadeOut('slow').delay(1000);
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

There is a similar script 'Refund' button in the 2nd tab, where I need move the item back to the 1st tab.

Comment: If all your wanting to show in the second tab is the `<b>Bill: </b> @item.TotSum`, then just move it from one tab to the other

Comment: And your `$(this).fadeOut('slow').delay(1000);` makes not sense - its already hidden

Comment: @StephenMuecke I wish to move the content inside `<div class="item">` in `tabs-1` to `tabs-2`. I typed "..." to shorten the question. I have `Item.Name`, `Date`, `TotSum` and more. I can't figure how to move the div. Thanks for pointing the hidden part.

Comment: Update the view with what your actually want to display in each tab (your first code snippet does not even have the correct closing tags/braces.

Comment: The most logical action to me is when you pay a bill send an ajax request and update your paid bill list, you can use partial views for that. Look here for an example: https://cmatskas.com/update-an-mvc-partial-view-with-ajax/

Comment: @YaserAdelMehraban, Using a partial view is not necessary at all.

Comment: So are you wanting exactly the same html in the 2nd tab, except for the `<button>`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry for faulty closing tags/braces. Got it wrong when I copied the code from project. It's corrected now. I also added a button in 2nd tab where user can refund (in `tabs-2`)

Comment: What does that button do? Is it also calling an ajax method (would it not also require the `ID` value)? And what happens in the success callback of that function?

Comment: @StephenMuecke To answer your latest comment: I wanting exactly the same html in the 2nd tab **with** a button, but instead "pay" button, I want "refund" button in tab 2.

Comment: That is easy enough to do, but it depends on what you 'Refund' button will be doing (particularly if that means that you move it back to the first tab)

Comment: @StephenMuecke You're right, missed `ID` in `refund`-button. It will call similar ajax method like I did for "pay": `$.post("/Home/Refund", { "id": refundId }, function(data) {`

Comment: But will clicking the 'Refund' button mean you want to move the item back to the first tab again? (in which case there are other issues with you code as well)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes. Like back and forward.

Comment: OK (that gets a bit more complicated). Need a break, but will add an answer in about 45 min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply move the `<div class="item">` element from one tab to another using `.append()` however, you need to change you scripts to use event delegation.

Start by removing the `style` attribute from the buttons and use css from styling

```
.btnPay {
    color: green;
}
.btnRefund{
    color: red;
}
```

And modify the scripts to use event delegation

```
var unpaid = $('#tabs-1');
var paid = $('#tabs-2');

unpaid.on('click', '.btnPay', function() {
    var button = $(this);
    var item = $(this).closest('.item');
    var payId = $(this).data('id');
    $.post('@Url.Action("PayBill", "Home")', { "id": payId }, function(data) {
        if (data) {
            item.slideUp(300, function() { // slowly hide the item
                paid.append(item); // move the item to the paid tab
                button.toggleClass('btnPay btnRefund'); // swap class names
                button.text('Refund'); // update button text
                item.show(); // show the item
            });
        }
    });
})

paid.on('click', '.btnRefund', function() {
    // as above except for the following lines (and the ajax url)
    uppaid.append(item); // move the item to the unpaid tab
    button.text('Pay'); // update button text
    });
})
```

Refer [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pp89futb/2/) for a simple example of how the code works.

Side note: I would recommend a view model with 2 collection properties (for paid and unpaid items) so that you can simply use `@foreach (var item in Model.UnpaidBills) { ... }` and `@foreach (var item in Model.PaidBills) { ... }` without the need for the `if` blocks.

Comment: Moving the div from `tabs-1` to `tabs-2` or vice versa works well. But it won't work moving them back. I commented out code inside ajax methods, and replaced with a simple `Alert`. I found out the ajax methods only triggers for real div that were generated when the page were loaded. The "fake/moved" div via ajax doesn't work with it for some odd reason.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment - the `<div>` has nothing to do with it. You need to use event delegation using the `on()` method as per my answer. And you can see that it does work - the fiddle proves it.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the `<div class="item">` element that I move from one tab to another via `.append()`. Ajax method stops working for the moved element. I'm not questioning your code, as I know your code works since I checked fiddle. Any idea what could cause it?

Comment: Oh nevermind..  `button.toggleClass('pay refund');` I forgot to change class names! Thanks, I am very grateful to you for your help.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `button.toggleClass('btnPay btnRefund');` :)